# Can I have a webpage that is an endless loop of a Powerpoint File

Tags: javascript, loops, powerpoint

Is there any way for me to run an endless loop of a .pptx file on a webpage. This would be the easiest way for me to display digital signage in certain locations.  I know there are programs/cloud services that would allow me to do this, but I am trying to keep this project as low cost as possible.

Thanks

If you think cycling images would be better, I am sure there is an easy script out there for that.

Answer (score 1):

In Powerpoint you can save a presentation as a movie, so you could just put that exported movie into a `<video>` tag and loop that.